# Javafx Control EventHandler MouseClicked All isxDown() methods false

Tags: java, javafx, eventhandler

I can't just know which button is clicked because all below methods are returning false. I am trying to grab the click type on a `HBox` control and using the code below. How to differentiate right and left click?

```
     hb.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event ->
    {
        System.out.println("Meta Down?" + event.isMetaDown());
        System.out.println("Middle Down?" + event.isMiddleButtonDown());
        System.out.println("Primary Down?" + event.isPrimaryButtonDown());
        System.out.println("Secondary Down?" + event.isSecondaryButtonDown());
        System.out.println("Synthesized?" + event.isSynthesized());
    }
```

***Output;***

```
Meta Down?false
       Middle Down?false
       Primary Down?false
       Secondary Down?false
       Synthesized?false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason none of them are down is because MouseClicked gets called when a mouse button is pressed and then released, in other words, it's a Mouse Pressed event followed by a Mouse Released event.

If you need to know what triggered it, look at the `event.getButton()` and see if it is any of the `MouseButton`s. Try changing your code to something like this:

```
hb.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event ->
{
    System.out.println("Middle Clicked?" + event.getButton()== MouseButton.MIDDLE);
    System.out.println("Primary Clicked?" + event.getButton()== MouseButton.PRIMARY);
    System.out.println("Secondary Clicked?" + event.getButton()== MouseButton.SECONDARY);
    System.out.println("None Clicked?" + event.getButton()== MouseButton.NONE);
}
```